# JasperReports with multiple detail bands

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am a beginner with JasperReports and wanted to have example of how to create a solution for the following problem.

I have details, and for each row in detail there are again details for that particular row. Can we implement this using JasperReports? I have tried creating sample reports using iReport for single detail band and that works fine, but don't know how to create a detail band which will have details for each row in existing detail band.

Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sub-report. Each row in the main report will contain a sub-report, which will itself have its own detail band.

You should find an example using a sub-report in the JasperReports distribution.

Comment: Niznet, I am searching for example, but if you know any particular link it will be really helpful. Also, I was quite confused about how to pass combined JRBeanCollectionDataSource for same.

Comment: As I said, if you download JasperReports, you'll find examples in the distribution.